# Algorithmic solutions Leda

Tags: algorithm

There is a LEDA program.

http://www.algorithmic-solutions.com/

which basically provides GUI to algorithms. I d like to get into that, I was curious if I can code with C# or JAVA for LEDA. I have looked at their website and googled it. But i didnt see any other languages beside c/c++,

Does anyone know if i can use C# or Java for LEDA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LEDA is a C++ library.  You could, theoretically, write wrappers to use this from Java or C#, but there are none included.

All of the samples will all require C++.

Comment: Can i find some wrapper classes that someone has already implemented?

Comment: I've never seen one.  LEDA is fairly heavy on the usage of C++ specific features, so a wrapper would end up being kind of "dumbbed down" to make it work, too.